# Given a matrix, how do you find entries of M^n?

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

If I am given a matrix $M=\begin{pmatrix} 13 & 1 \\ -16 & 5 \end{pmatrix}$

I need to find formulas for the entries of$ M^n$, where $n$ is a positive integer. I first calculated all the eigenvalues which are 9.So the eigenvector is: $$ \left[ \begin{matrix}
-1/4\\
1\\
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$.

I know that $M = PDP^{-1}$, so $ M^n = PD^nP^{-1}$.

So,
$D=\begin{pmatrix} 9^n & 1 \\ 0 & 9^n \end{pmatrix}$

and  $P=\begin{pmatrix} -1 & -1/4 \\ 4 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

so is $P^{-1}$ $=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1/4 \\ -4 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$

so $M^n$ = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & -1/4 \\ 4 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 9^n & 1 \\ 0 & 9^n \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1/4 \\ -4 & -1 \end{pmatrix}

which gives
\begin{pmatrix} 9^n+4 & 1 \\ -16 & 9^n-4\end{pmatrix}

But it is wrong. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please don't use pictures. You can type a matrix by writing`$M=\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$` $M=\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$ For learning how to type other mathematics you can get started [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33179/80734), a more complete reference can be found [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Regarding the maths: yes, $P$ is wrong. You should have two eigenvectors (or possibly one generalized eigenvector).

Comment: Is P supposed to be (-1 4)?

Comment: You should consult the [great big cloud in the sky](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=diagonalize+%7B%7B13%2C1%7D%2C%7B-16%2C5%7D%7D)

Comment: Please make use of Calvin Khor's typesetting comments. It may sound like an aesthetic detail, but it's actually not. It makes it easier for the search engine to index the content, and it also makes it easier to read for people to read and then answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The characteristic equation is

$ | \lambda I - M | = (\lambda - 13)(\lambda - 5) + 16 = \lambda^2 - 18 \lambda + 81 =(\lambda - 9)^2$

It roots are $9$ with algebraic multiplicity of $2$.

Now we find the eigenvectors

Let $v = [v_1 , v_2]^T $ then we have to solve the system

$ (\lambda I - M) v = 0 $

which is

$ \begin{bmatrix} -4 && -1 \\ 16 && 4 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$

The solutions is

$\begin{bmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \end{bmatrix} = t \begin{bmatrix} -\frac{1}{4} \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} $

Since there is only one eigenvector, we have to generate a generalized eigenvector as follows

$ (M - \lambda I) u = v $

so that

$ \begin{bmatrix} 4 && 1 \\ -16 && -4 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} u_1 \\u_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -\frac{1}{4} \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} $

The system is consistent, and has the solution

$ \begin{bmatrix} u_1 \\ u_2 \end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{4}(-\frac{1}{4} - t) \\ t \end{bmatrix} $

Put $t = 1$ you get

$ u = \begin{bmatrix} -\dfrac{5}{16} \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} $

So now

$ M [ v, u] = [\lambda v , v + \lambda u ] = \begin{bmatrix} v, u \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \lambda && 1 \\ 0 && \lambda \end{bmatrix} $

so that we can take

$P = [v, u] = \begin{bmatrix} -\frac{1}{4} && -\frac{5}{16} \\ 1 && 1 \end{bmatrix} $

then

$M = P J P^{-1}$
where

$J = \begin{bmatrix} \lambda && 1 \\ 0 && \lambda \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 9 && 1 \\ 0 && 9 \end{bmatrix} $

Note that $P$ is not unique, we could have chosen

$ v = \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 4 \end{bmatrix} $

and by setting $t = 0$ results in

$ u = \begin{bmatrix} -\frac{1}{4} \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} $

so that

$ P = \begin{bmatrix} -1 && -\frac{1}{4} \\ 4 && 0 \end{bmatrix} $

Now,

$M^n = P J^n P^{-1} $

You can show by induction, or otherwise, that

$J^n = \begin{bmatrix} 9^n && n (9)^{n-1} \\ 0 && 9^n \end{bmatrix}$

and from this you can compute $M^n$

$M^n = \begin{bmatrix} -\frac{1}{4} && -\frac{5}{16} \\ 1 && 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 9^n && n (9)^{n-1} \\ 0 && 9^n \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 16 && 5 \\ -16 && -4 \end{bmatrix} $

Multiplying out the first two matrices

$M^n = \begin{bmatrix} - \dfrac{9^n}{4} && -\frac{9^{n-1}}{16} (4 n + 45 ) \\ 9^n && 9^{n-1} ( n + 9 ) \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 16 && 5 \\ -16 && -4 \end{bmatrix} $

and this becomes

$M^n = \begin{bmatrix} 9^{n-1} ( 4n + 9 ) && 9^{n-1} n \\ -16 n (9)^{n-1}  && 9^{n-1} (9 - 4n) \end{bmatrix} = 9^{n-1} \begin{bmatrix} 4 n + 9 && n \\ -16 n && 9 - 4n \end{bmatrix} $

I checked $M^2 $ by direct calculation and using the above expression, and they match.